# Как изменить тег views с h4 на p Drupal?

Tags: html, css, drupal

Как изменить тег в представлениях views , хочу изменить тег заголовка на с на ? в каком файле это редактировать? не могу найти код где это можно поменять

Answer (score 0):

Прописать в settings.php

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

Тогда в раметке коментариями будет показано какой шаблон используеться для вывода views. Посмотрите какой используеться.

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x semanticviews-view-fields--default.tpl.php
   * semanticviews-view-fields.tpl.php
-->
```

Найдите его, потом подберите шаблон с большым приоритетом и создайте его в своей теме в директории `templates`. Не пишите его с нуля, просто скопируйте контент с рабочего шаблона и замените то что нужно.

Так же можно использовать pre_render_views но это как на меня не так логично, менять разметку в методах. Как на меня лучше менять ее уже при выводе.

Если нужно упростить разметку вывода смотрите в сторону [Semantic Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/semanticviews)